# How to create an alert dialog with radio button on the side?

Tags: android

How to create an `AlertDialog` with `RadioButton` on the side?
I can create a `Dialog` with 3 selection strings using `AlertDialog.Builder`, but how can I create the one with `RadioButton` on the side (i.e. allow only 1 selection)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you are using Material Design or not or whether or not you still need this answered after 6 years, but for anybody who may be looking for this, here is the answer

```
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                        .title(R.string.which_phone_number)
                        .items(contactPhonesArr)
                        .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(0, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                                    //Do really cool things here
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        })
                        .positiveText("Choose")
                        .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
AlertDialog levelDialog;
// Strings to Show In Dialog with Radio Buttons
final CharSequence[] items = {" Easy "," Medium "," Hard "," Very Hard "};
// Creating and Building the Dialog 
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select The Difficulty Level");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        // Your code
        levelDialog.dismiss();    
    }
});
levelDialog = builder.create();
levelDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setView()` in `AlertDialog.Builder`, perhaps? It is tough to tell what "the one with radio button on the side" means.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how can I use setView() to have 2 lines of text in AlertDialog?
where the first line is header , the second line is description?

Comment: It sounds as if Preferences might be what you're looking for.. http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences/

Comment: Is it possible to configure ListPreference to have 2 line of text instead of 1?
Thanks.